# How to override ommiauth library method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, omniauth

I am new to ruby and trying to override the omniauth library method. I would like to make it support env.header [Please see this pull request on omniauth](https://github.com/intridea/omniauth/pull/806/files). So how can I make this changes in my project?

Answer (score 0):

In Ruby classes can simply override any methods provided by a mixin (an included module):

```
module Strategy
  def self.included(base)
    base.extend ClassMethods
  end

  module ClassMethods
    def hello
      "Hello from Strategy"
    end
  end  
end

class MyStrategy
  include Strategy

  def self.hello
    "Hello from MyStrategy"
  end
end

puts MyStrategy.hello
```

Which means that a Strategy author can simply override any of the methods when authoring a strategy class. So you can simply override the `request_call` method in your strategy instead which is a better alternative since most strategies do not need all the request headers to be stored in the session.

Since `OmniAuth::Strategy` is a module rather than a class you cannot use `super` to call the original method. What you can do instead is to alias the mixin method before overriding it in your class:

```
module OmniAuth
  class MyStrategy
    include Strategy

    class << self
      alias :original_request_call :request_call 
    end

    def self.request_call
      session['omniauth.headers'] = headers
      original_request_call
    end

    # ...
  end
end
```

The weird alias syntax is because its not a method but rather syntactic sugar.

Comment: PS. Welcome to stackoverflow, when you create a question here you should include the relevant code or at least a minimal example. If you only link to a github repository you will get downvoted and your question may be closed.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It is very useful in my case. However, I would like to know is it mean I need to write my own Strategy for my use case? I prefered to add this function with omniauth-facebook.

Comment: In that case you would either create a subclass of FacebookStrategy or monkeypatch the class at runtime. The later can have serious maintainence problems.